# Is writing "std::" before stoi(s.substr(2,3)) mandatory?

Tags: c++

I have seen that even if you don't add `std::` before `stoi(s.substr(3,4))` (where `s="123456789"`) it works fine, and also if you write `std::stoi(s.substr(3,4))` the result is the same. So, is writing it like `std::stoi(s.substr(3,4))` mandatory, or is it just good practice?

```cpp
std::string s = "123456789";
int ans = stoi(s.substr(3,4));
std::cout<<ans;
```

```cpp
std::string s = "123456789";
int ans = std::stoi(s.substr(3,4));
std::cout<<ans;
```

Both gives the same answer. And also sometimes writing `std::stoi(s.substr(3,4));` gives an error.

Comment: _"...sometimes writing `std::stoi(s.substr(3,4));` gives an error."_ That may be because you have not included the appropriate library i.e. `#include <string>`

Comment: Note: even with something really simple like this a [mre] is helpful. It filters out the wrong answers from assuming you have a `using namespace std;` in there somewhere. Also lets an answerer pinpoint exactly what the failure case is.

Answer (score 11):

It compiles without `std::` because of the [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

I say it's a good practice to use `std::stoi` because:

- It's more obvious that a standard function is being called.
- It will not break if someone defines a variable named `stoi` prior to your code. This can be fixed by adding `using std::stoi;`, but since you call it once, it's more verbose than calling `std::stoi` directly.

Comment: @LameThings You're welcome! You can click the checkmark next to one of the answers (usually the most helpful one) to mark your question as solved.

Comment: @LameThings Furthermore, if you tried to call for example `stoi("1234")`, it wouldn't work because ADL cannot find `std` from the string literal. `std::stoi("1234")` does work because of the implicit converting constructor of `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered good practice to add std:: namespace, so you can avoid conflicts if you use different libraries etc.
The probable reason it gives you an error sometimes is because you probably don't include the string header of the standard library:

```
#include <string>
```

but it is difficult without seeing the error, so please provide the details

Answer (score 0):

Likely, if you can use `stoi` and get the same result as `std::stoi`, you might be `using namespace std` already.

This is not always desirable, depending on the project philosophy and the rest of your code suggests that you shouldn't depend on it.

edit: in this case, OP does not use `using namespace std` and [something more subtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68895122/15304) is going on (thanks @HolyBlackCat).

Comment: No, even if i am not using "using namespace std" in header. It still works fine. And that's the reason why I am confused

Comment: @LameThings Sidenote: Never do `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in header files.

Comment: hopefully, @HolyBlackCat nailed it. I didn't know about the auto-lookup technique he mentions. I'd have got my foot++ shot here too, apparently.

Comment: It's ADL - Argument Dependent Lookup, also called Koenig lookup. It looks for functions and operators in the namespaces of the types of their arguments. So it works for `stoi` because it takes a `std::string` as argument. If it took, say, `const char *` - it would not work anymore, because that type isn't in the `std` namespace.

Comment: That's why, for example, `stoi` "just works", `strtol` doesn't, but `std::strtol` is fine. If you don't know that ADL exists, I'm sure it can drive a person nuts. On top of that, IIRC C++ library implementations are free to offer `strtol` in global namespace, but it's not portable. So, worse yet, often `strol` will compile anyway, until it doesn't. E.g. when someone helpfully converts the deprecated headers like `<stdlib.h>` to `<cstdlib>`. With the latter, `strtol` outside of `std::` is entirely optional...

Answer (score 0):

`stoi()` exists in the `std` namespace, so using `stoi()` without `std::` works if there is a preceding `using namespace std;` or `using std::stoi;` statement, or when passing in a `std::string` object as an argument value due to [Argument-Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (since `string` and `stoi()` are in the same namespace).

Comment: ...and `#include <string>` exists somewhere

Comment: ...or one of the argument types happens to be in the `std::` namespace :) ADL is an essential feature for sanity in operator invocation at the point of use; iostream operators would be useless without it. but I'm still unsure if it was a good idea to make it affect all functions, not just operators. It fills the world full of handy ghost crutches that can materialize at any moment. Those sometimes make it harder to see what's going on, and it demonstrably doesn't discriminate in tripping up just about everybody :) Bit me many times as well, no mistake.

Comment: Heck, I've wasted a good half an hour seeing how exactly ADL was slightly messing things up just this last night during a prolonged hacking session... it's an equal opportunity beartrap.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica good point, I keep forgetting about ADL.